# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject issue in WebAPI Response result - C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, json-deserialization

I'm having a Model class it has one GENERIC property in one of the WebAPI, while on invoking the WebAPI Controller method via HttpGet, its returning the object, but I can't able to DE-serialize the response JSON. If I tried to copy the JSON string into a local variable (Hardcoded value of Response) its DE-serializing well, but in dynamic its failing.  Kindly look the model classes

Generic Model Class:

```
public class Response<T> {
    public T Person { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Employee Model Class:

```
public class Employee {
    public string EmpId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string OrganizationName { get; set; }
}

public class Celebrity {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
}
```

I'm having a JSON string of type `Response<Celebrity>`

Consider the WebAPI Controller method

```
public class PersonController : ApiController {

    [HttpGet]
    public Response<Celebrity> GetPerson() {
        return new Response<Celebrity>()
        {
            Person = new Celebrity()
            {
                FirstName = "Emma",
                LastName = "Watson",
                Language = "English"
            },
            Mobile = "222123456",
            Email = "emma@gmail.com"
        };
    }
}
```

In console application I'm Invoking the WebAPI Controller method and its not DE-serializing.

```
string jsonContent = string.Empty;

var apiResponse = ApiClient.GetAsync("GetPerson").Result;
if (apiResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
    jsonContent = apiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    Response<Celebrity> person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response<Celebrity>>(jsonContent);
}
```

I tried the following approach

**Step: #1** I copied the value of `apiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result`

```
{"Result":{"FirstName":"Emma","LastName":"Watson","Language":"English"},"Mobile":"222123456","Email":"emma@gmail.com"}
```

**Step: #2** I used the hardcode value of Step #1

```
string jsonContent = "{\"Result\":{\"FirstName\":\"Emma\",\"LastName\":\"Watson\",\"Language\":\"English\"},\"Mobile\":\"222123456\",\"Email\":\"emma@gmail.com\"}";

Response<Celebrity> person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response<Celebrity>>(jsonContent);
```

Its working. I don't know what I missed.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem with the encoding of the API response. This would also explain why the hardcoded value works.

Therefore try the following code and see if it works:

```
string rawApiResponseString = apiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
string jsonContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(rawApiResponseString));

Response<Celebrity> person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response<Celebrity>>(jsonContent);
```

EDIT:

Try if the following code works:

```
string jsonContent = apiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
Celebrity person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Celebrity>(jsonContent);
```

The JSON `string` seems to be a serialized `Celebrity` and not a `Response<Celebrity>`.

Comment: Still I'm getting the same issue.

Comment: @Mastero do you get an exception or does it just not deserialize?

Comment: No. I'm not getting any exception I'm getting a default instance of the model, nothing is assigned.

Comment: @Mastero see if my edit works for you, I think it should

Comment: @Mastero good, please notice  me of the results so I can help you further

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146618/discussion-between-thfl-and-mastero).

Answer (score 0):

if you haven't found a solution, this might help you. can you try adding the Attributes, "DataContractAttribute" to the class and "DataMemberAttribute" to all the public members and try?

Both Attributes are in the Namespace "System.Runtime.Serialization" you can add this reference using the "Add Reference" and choosing "Assemblies", "Framework".

Basically your modified class should look something like this

Response Class

```
[DataContract]
public class Response<T> {
    [DataMember]
    public T Person { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Employee Model Class

```
[DataContract]
public class Employee {
   [DataMember]
    public string EmpId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string OrganizationName { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class Celebrity {
    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Language { get; set; }
}
```